# How to merge 3 dict lists in python3 by their order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I having an issue of finding a way to merge these three lists into one in Python3.

```
list1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'a': '2'}, {'a': '3'}]
list2 = [{'b': '4'}, {'b': '5'}, {'b': '6'}]
list3 = [{'c': '7'}, {'c': '8'}, {'c': '9'}]
```

What I would like to do is getting a new list such as:

```
list4 = [{'a': '1', 'b': '4', 'c': '7'}, {'a': '2', 'b': '5', 'c': '8'}, {'a': '3', 'b': '6', 'c': '9'}]
```

Is there any Pythonic way to do this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `zip` in a combined list- and dict comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = [{'a': '1'}, {'a': '2'}, {'a': '3'}]
>>> list2 = [{'b': '4'}, {'b': '5'}, {'b': '6'}]
>>> list3 = [{'c': '7'}, {'c': '8'}, {'c': '9'}]
>>> [{k: d[k] for d in ds for k in d} for ds in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
[{'a': '1', 'b': '4', 'c': '7'},
 {'a': '2', 'b': '5', 'c': '8'},
 {'a': '3', 'b': '6', 'c': '9'}]
```

Also works if the dicts contain more than one value. If the dicts in one "column" contain the same keys, the values in the later lists will overwrite the former.